# Android Studio : ошибка "cannot resolve symbol MainActivity". Как исправить?

Tags: java, android

Ошибка "cannot resolve symbol MainActivity". В тестовом классе ссылка на класс MainActivity выделена красным цветом:

```
 int actualValue = MainActivity.power(2,3);
```

в Андроид Студио в Project папка test (в src) выглядит недействующей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя путь в файловой системе указан верно. Проект собран, сделана синхронизация, чистка, File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart - ничего не помогает. Как исправить?

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Example local unit test, which will execute on the development machine (host).
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */

        public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void power_test1 () {
        int expected = 8;
        int actualValue = MainActivity.power(2,3);

        assertEquals(expected,actualValue);

    }

         @Test
    public void power_test2 () {
        int expected = 0;
        int actualValue = MainActivity.power(2,101);

        assertEquals(expected,actualValue);

    }

}
```

Comment: она не выглядит недействующей, красное подчеркивание означает, что в этом месте, в данном случае в файле ExampleUnitTest есть ошибка.

Comment: приведите пожалуйста весь код который находится в проблемной файле, по одной строке сложно определить проблему :(

Comment: Извините, я новичок, как мне поместить код? Править - Описание- и туда вставить скопированный код?  Или скриншот?

Comment: править, и туда вставьте то что у вас в этом файле

Comment: `unitTest` выполняется на ПК в обычной JVM (JavaSE) - соответственно ему недоступны большинство классов из Android SDK (от которых зависит ваша `MainActivity`). Либо вы должны убрать эти зависимости, либо [подменить](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests#mockable-library) их, либо перенести ваш тест в `androidTest`, который выполняется на Андроид устройстве/эмуляторе

Comment: В задании  нужно выполнить юнит-тесты без привлечения  любых андроид-девайсов (реальных и эмуляторов), но с вызовом static-метода через класс MainActivity. То есть, мне, наверное, надо не убирать эти зависимости, а подменить? Правда, еще не понятно, на какие. Пока только учусь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня идентичное задание. Попробуй File -> Project Structure -> Project и выставить такие же значения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если не поможет, попробуй еще в файле AndroidManifest.xml поменять первые 3 строки на:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
              и т.д.
```

Comment: Да, верно, помогло! Андрей, спасибо огромное!